# Jmeter with open id authentication

Tags: jmeter

When i am trying access web application on azure cloud its going through multiple level of authentication before reaching the home page where actual steps needs to be performed.

below is the list of authentication

1. dev-connect.aveva.com
2. aveva.com
3. microsoftonline.com
4. msauth.net
5. capdev-connect.aveva.com

As a result of which we are unable to record the jmx scripts fully.
Whatever is recorded when run it on Jmeter it fails to authenticate .

Can anyone me on this issue ?

Regards
Zuheb Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

There must be an authentication token that are required to perform the test. What you need to do is use a header manager and include that token so that whenever you run your test it runs successfully until the authentication token is expired.

Answer (score 0):

In case of 3rd-party authentication provider you cannot just record and replay the test successfully, you will need to perform some [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) first in order to fully simulate authentication flow and replace recorded hard-coded values with the dynamic values from the requests.

The easiest way of recording the same scenario one more time and compare generated JMeter scripts, all the values which differ need to be correlated using suitable [JMeter Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), saved into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and used in next requests.

Check out [OpenID Connect - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/openid-connect-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter/) article for example challenge and solution, you will not be able to copy and paste it as you're using a different identity provider, but it will give you some initial information regarding which direction you should be moving.